# mongoose two level array population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate three collection but I think I'm missing something.

```
var BlogsSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
url: {type:String, unique: true},
_rows: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Rows'}],
description: String,
tags:[{type:String}]
});
var RowsSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
text: String,
_asset: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Assets'
}
});



Blogs.find()
    .populate('_rows')
    .populate('_rows._asset')
    .exec(function (err, blogs) {
        if (!err) {
            var _id = [];
            return res.json(blogs);
        } else {
            return res.send(err);
        }
    });
```

I couldn't populate the _asset. This responds:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "532acfa26f192fdc1e000002",
  "description": "deneme deneme",
  "name": "Deneme",
  "url": "deneme",
  "tags": [
    "deneme1",
    "deneme2"
  ],
  "_rows": [
    {
      "name": "asdfadf",
      "text": "asdfadsf",
      "_id": "532acfa96f192fdc1e000003",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "asdfsfdb",
      "text": "bodfbsdfbsdbsdb",
      "_asset": "5327ca7006777b6c0e000003", // this should populated too. Not _id
      "_id": "532acfe36f192fdc1e000004",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as mongoose doesn't give option for nested population in current version.

You need to iterate through the `_rows` array and manually populate the `_rows._asset`